# Analysis, limit of $(3n)!/(n!)^3$

Tags: real-analysis

How do you show that $(3n)!/(n!)^3$ doesn't have a limit as n goes to infinity?

Comment: Consider the quotient of two successive terms.

Comment: Does the ratio test work for sequences to show divergence?

Comment: You can also use Stirling approximation.

Comment: Suppose $a_n \to a \ne 0$. What can you say about $a_{n+1}/a_n$?

Comment: If $a_n \neq 0$, and you have a constant $c < 1$ with $\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert \leqslant c$ for all large enough $n$, then you can deduce that the sequence converges to $0$. If you have a $C > 1$ with $\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert \geqslant C$ for all large enough $n$, then you can conclude that the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: Interpretation: That is the number of distinct ways to arrange $3n$ objects in a line, of which $n$ are of type $a$, $n$ of type $b$ and $n$ of type $c$, and any two objects of the same type are indistinguishable.

Comment: If, as suggested by Arash, you use Stirling's approximation, your expression simplifies to 3^(3 n + 1/2)/(2 n Pi) which increases very fast.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}=\frac{(3n)!}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n!)^2}=\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n)!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}$$
$$\binom{3n}{n}=\frac{\underbrace{3n(3n-1)\cdots(2n+1)}_{n\;\text{terms}>n}}{n!}\geq\binom{3n}{1}=3n\to\infty$$
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{\underbrace{2n(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)}_{n\;\text{terms}>n}}{n!}\ge\binom{2n}{1}=2n\to\infty$$
$$\implies\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}\ge 6n^2\to\infty$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}=\infty$$
Therefore, it has to be divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(n) = \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$ counts the number of ways to arrange $n$ As, $n$ Bs, and $n$ Cs in a row where the same letters are indistinguishable.

Now, given any arrangement string $S$ with $n$ of each letter, if we append "$ABC$" to $S,$ then we obtain a string $SABC,$ which is an arrangement with $n+1$ of each letter. Doing this to each such arrangement yields $f(n)$ distinct arrangements.
Similarly, we can append any permutation of "$ABC$" to the end of $S$ as well. Clearly all of these yield distinct arrangements with $n+1$ of each letter.

Thus, we have $f(n+1) \geq 6 f(n)$ for all $n$ and $f(1) = 6,$ so the sequence increases without bound.

**Remark:** You can also directly note that $f(n) \geq 6^n$ by splitting the letters into consecutive groups of (ABC)s in threes where letters within a group are adjacent to each other, and permuting within each group.