# Prove that the sequence is convergent: $(3n)!/(n!)^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Prove that the sequence is convergent:

$$
\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}
$$

I know that it will converge at $27$, but how will you prove it is a bounded sequence?

Comment: Done ! What is the next question ? Back to serious, first *Welcome to the site !*. Second : if you do not show your work, there is vary little chance you get any help. Edit your post and explain what you have done and where you are stuck. Cheers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think that you would have an easier time proving that it was divergent.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is that the ratio of consecutive terms converges to $27$. Indeed, as $n\to\infty$,$$\frac{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=27\underbrace{\frac{1+\frac{1}{3n}}{1+\frac2n}}_{\to1}\underbrace{\frac{1+\frac{2}{3n}}{1+\frac3n}}_{\to1}\to27.$$

Answer (score 0):

The result is erroneous.

Using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), the general term is equivalent to

$$\dfrac{(3n/e)^{3n}\sqrt{6 \pi n}}{((n/e)^{n}\sqrt{2 \pi n})^3}=k \dfrac{3^{3n}}{n}$$

with constant $k=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \pi}$, which is divergent.

Connected : [Analysis, limit of $(3n)!/(n!)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534969).

Maybe your error comes from confusion with $\dfrac{3^{3}n}{n}=27$.