# Finding convergence of series using Ratio Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have this series but Im not too sure whether my calculations are correct
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}\right) $$
$$  \left( \frac{(3(n+1)!}{((n+1)!)^3}\right)\cdot\left( \frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right) $$
$$  \left( \frac{(3(n+1)(3n)!}{((n+1)^3(n!)^3}\right)\cdot\left( \frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right) $$
and by simplifying I got to
$$  \left( \frac{(3(n+1)}{(n+1)^3}\right) $$
$$  \left( \frac{(3n+3)}{(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)}\right) = 0 $$
so the series is convergent by Ratio test.

Comment: Your question is hard to read. All I see is lines of formulas' with no links between. What is this line supposed to mean on it's own $$  \left( \frac{(3(n+1)}{(n+1)^3}\right) ?$$ Why does $$ \left( \frac{(3n+3)}{(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)}\right) = 0 ?$$  when this equality isn't verified for all values of $n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: wont it equal 0 when dividing everything by n^3

Comment: No plug in $n = 1$ and you will see that $$  \left( \frac{(3n+3)}{(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)}\right) \neq 0 $$. Perhaps you're thinking of taking a limit ? This isn't clear from what you wrote.   What I'm trying to tell you is that the way you wrote out your question is not clear. You say you're not sure if your calculations are correct but where are these calculations you speak of ? What are the logical links between each line here ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534969/analysis-limit-of-3n-n3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your first step, indeed by ratio test we obtain

$$ \frac{(3n+3)!}{((n+1)!)^3} \frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}=\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^3} $$

since $(3(n+1))!=(3n+3)!$.

---

To avoid ratio test we can use that

- $(3n)! =3n\cdot(3n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1) \cdot n!\ge (n+1)^{2n} \cdot n! \ge n^{2n} \cdot n!$

and then

$$ \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3} \ge \left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^2 \to \infty$$